# Many-to-Many categories and products with specific category orders for users

Tags: php, database, symfony, database-design, relational-database

For each user, we should be able to change and save the order of the categories. Enabling and disabling the categories and products for each user must be possible. Currently, we have the user, product, category, and product_category tables.

I would create the Many-to-Many tables user_product and user_category:

user_category:

```
user_id | category_id | order | active
1       | 1           | 2     | 1
1       | 2           | 1     | 0
```

user_product

```
user_id | product_id | active
1       | 3          | 1
2       | 2          | 0
```

Is that a good approach? Are there other possibilities?

Comment: I think that's a fair approach. Personally I like separation so I would have a `user_category_info` table with `user_category_id, order, active`. I'm not saying this is the right approach but how I would have done it. I'm interested to see other opinions.

Comment: Plain Many-To-Many is actually quite rare... Most of the time, as you want to add custom fields, you will build another entity, which will serve as bridge for the two others, and use Many-To-One/One-To-Many relation. Look at the comment just above point 5.9 http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: As other comments say, it is a pretty valid approach. Just keep in mind to do eager loading correctly so you do not end up going to database back-and-forth...